# How to horizontally centre a stars rating image within a Bootstrap column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a stars rating image which is controlled using Javascript and CSS to display a rating out of five (in quarter steps, twenty is the dimensions of the star in pixels):

[image: stars.png]

```
$.fn.stars = function() {
    return $(this).each(function() {
        var val = Math.round(parseFloat($(this).html())*4)/4;
        var size = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, val)))*20;
        var $span = $("<span />").width(size);
        $(this).html($span);
    });
}

$(function() {
    $("#avg-rating").html('<span class="stars">{{ avg_rating }}</span>');
});

span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url(stars.png) 0 -20px repeat-x;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
span.stars span {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

The image is displayed in a Bootstrap column:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6"><div id="avg-rating"></div></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">blah blah</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image is currently left justified in its column.  I have tried several things in CSS to align the image horizontally in its column, such as adjusting the display attribute or background position.  But I am unable to move the image without upsetting the functionality of the image manipulation.

**Update**

Using inline-block instead of block messes up the placement of the stars (image should show four lighted stars out of five):

```
span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: inline-block;
...
```

[image: stars mess]

Comment: Can you post a full working snippet on fiddle or bootply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to stem from here:

```
span.stars, span.stars span {
    display: block;
    background: url(stars.png) 0 -20px repeat-x;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

You've set the star container to 'display: block' which makes it take up the whole line. You want it to be an inline-block with a width smaller than the full-width available so that it can be centred.

Here is an example of how it would work:
https://jsfiddle.net/f6L8gr1b/2/

Comment: There is a problem with using that solution, see my update!

Comment: @tyebillion you should have a wrapper div which is set to full width. The div/span inside of that with the stars should be a fixed width just to show 5 stars, but it can remain left aligned. Then you need to centre the stars container within the wrapper div using margin: 0 auto; on the star container.

Comment: Ah Thanks.  I didn't do exaclty what you said, but instead I just put another div around the "avg-rating" div, with an inline-block style.

Comment: @tyebillion I made an example for you to see what I meant: https://jsfiddle.net/f6L8gr1b/

Answer (score 1):

If your elements with class "col-xs-6" are supposed to be next to each other horizontally, you can use inline-block.

```
.col-xs-6 {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The div elements default to block which places them on a new line.